# Can a Flesh Golem benefit from the 7th-level Regenerate spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, constructs, regeneration

Traditionally, the [flesh golem](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Flesh%20Golem#content) is [alive... it's ALIVE!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qNeGSJaQ9Q). Not so with 5e D&D of course, it is just another automaton but made with soggy RAW parts. Too bad of course (some amazing clips and reels of lore just... left on the cutting room floor as it were) - but RAW is RAW.

For reasons I cannot find in the monster description, golems cannot benefit from most healing spells. It must be under 'general golem characteristics' or something. I cannot find it. I also searched Stack Exchange a few times to see if this was already answered a few times. (Forgive me if I missed it.)

Sometimes there are exceptions to general rules. In this case, the 7th-level spell [*regenerate*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Regenerate#content) seems to be pretty darn powerful. New limbs in just two minutes! That's the stuff.

Now I get that this should *not* work with golems of any other material (such as stone, iron or clay). If it did RAW, I still would not allow it as a DM. But this would be a great way of rebuilding a fleshy-robot-person-thing when lightning can 'heal' but not rebuild.

---

**Can a flesh golem benefit from the 7th-level spell *regenerate*** (assuming it is missing a severed body part of some kind)?

Comment: When you say "For reasons I cannot find in the monster description, golems cannot benefit from most healing spells.", are you talking about you not knowing the narrative/lore reason that most spells say they don't work on constructs, or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### As written, *regenerate* can heal flesh golems

Specifically, there is no rule which stops it. *Regenerate* has no clause which limits what creatures are targetable, and flesh golems have no trait which limits their healing.  The Monster Manual (p.6) is clear that these are the only places such a rule can come from:

> Certain spells, magic items, class features, and other
> effects in the game interact in special ways with
> creatures of a particular type.
>
> The game includes the following monster types, which
> have no rules of their own.

The notion of them not being healable by most healing spells stems from them being Constructs, and many healing spells – for example [*cure wounds*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cure-wounds) – having no effect on such:

> This spell has no effect on undead or constructs.

The only remaining matter would be whether regaining limbs counts as altering the creatures form, in which case the Immutable Form trait would apply:

> **Immutable Form.** The golem is immune to any spell or effect that would alter its form.

Though in that case the spell or effect which caused the loss of limbs is presumably also altering the creatures form, rendering the question moot.

Comment: That's what i thought. Wow. It is weird to think because the parts it regenerates were formerly from one or more random people. Yet, there it is! Thank you very much.

Comment: You may find it helpful to mention the spell's "flavor text": "You touch a creature and stimulate its natural healing ability." The MM description of the Flesh golem tells us that it has a natural healing ability: " If the spirit breaks free of its creator’s will, the golem goes berserk until calmed, or until its shell of flesh is destroyed or completely healed."

Comment: @ThomasMarkov So it makes healing-powers where no healing has gone before. Thus 'regeneration' would work on stone and iron golems as well? Oh dear: how about a *Simulacrum* from spell? Oh no... do i have to write another question?

Comment: @TimofTime You don't necessarily have to write another question, I think Someone_Evil has given you all the tools you need to work those out on your own, what do you think?

Comment: @TimofTime We have a plethora of questions regarding healing simulacra, I'd recommend reviewing those first before posting a question about it.